# How to count characters containg an html object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to figure out how to count all the characters of an html string using jquery:

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" id="basic">
```

I wanna do something like:

```
var object = $('#basic');
var characters = object.numberOfCharacters;
```

The answer should be = 67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the 'outer' HTML property to get the tag/element selected and then count the length of that element.

See sample code below

```js
$(function() {
  let linkObj = $('#basic');
  console.log(linkObj.prop('outerHTML').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" id="basic">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
$('#basic')[0].outerHTML.length
```

There isn't really a jQuery function available for this purpose, but luckily Vanilla-Javascript is capable of getting the `.outerHTML` property directly from the (first) selected DOM element of the jQuery object.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this in jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <div>
            <h1>Testing Log</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        var content = $('#myDiv').html();
        console.log(content);
        //remove white spaces
        content = content.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\n/g, '');
        var characterCount = content.length;
        console.log('count:', characterCount);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think the sample code you provided does what you think it does.  Did you try it?

Comment: Updated version added.

Comment: OP wants to know the length of the tag: `<div id="myDiv">` not the length of the inner HTML of the element selected